# Warped space shouldn't cause movement in Gravity so what does?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, spacetime, geodesics

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding for how gravity works and have been reading various explanations from answers here to Sean Carroll and others' youtube videos. I have a set of university physics books but surprisingly they deal overwhelmingly with classical physics.

I'm wondering what it is that is causing the inertia of a 'static' object to start moving in the direction of gravity?

Now I understand that everything (possibly) is moving under the influence of some graviational field all the time. If not from earth's gravity then from the sun's, or the black holes in the center of the Milky Way.

I read that it's the warping of SpaceTime.
But if I just distort a coordinate system or a 3 dimensional grid, that in itself should not generate the acceleration I feel. It should just displace the coordinates in that 'space structure'.

I read about Geodesics but that does not to me explain anything. For the apple falling its clear that the shortest path is towards the center of the earth and that's not very surprising. It doesn't seem that just because a path is shortest something should automatically get pulled along it.

So, what is it that causes the pull(push)?

Cheers!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127622/discussion-on-question-by-redmarsbluemoon-warped-space-shouldnt-cause-movement).